# Office document rendering issue in Microsoft Teams with Edge Dev browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams, webview2

I working with the Microsoft Edge Dev browser (the last updated) and Microsoft Teams onLine with an Office365 account. I uploaded a Word file (docx) in a team and if I want to open the file in Word Online (the Microsoft Teams document viewer) or in Sharepoint, I have a viewing issue. You can see black screen here [PrintScreen Word Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DGRqx7NBaHWRozjWyeADljfePtXaMlcK/view?usp=sharing)

It doesn't work with Office documents neither (Word, Excel PowerPoint files).

But it works with older Office documents format (which are not built with openxml structure). So I supposed there is an issue for viewing openxml documents in Microsoft Teams with Microsoft Edge Dev browser.

I don't know if it's the right place to post that issue. I also post this article in EdgeInsiderDiscussions forum on techcommunity.microsoft.com

Thanks for considering it.

Comment: Can you try uploading a file to any other team and test it there? Please reach out to Microsoft Teams [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) if the issues persists.

Comment: Yes I tried many times with different Office document in many different teams and always the same issue. No issues with older Office documents. I will post it in product support channels. Thanks.